# JSF, ajax and commandLink, don't redirect?

Tags: ajax, jsf, commandlink

I'm wonking on a jsf application, i want to use commandLink to execute ana action on my managed bean, where there is a server call, but i dont want to reload the page, i've tried with a commandButton and the attribut update it works?
How can i make this with commandLink ?

I resolved the problem by using the commadLink of primefaces 3.2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Just return `null` or `void` from the action method.

```
<h:commandLink value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
    <f:ajax />
</h:commandLink>
```

with

```
public void submit() {
    // ...
}
```

You can also use the `<f:ajax listener>` attribute instead.

```
<h:commandLink value="submit">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:commandLink>
```